# If-else statement on haar cascade application

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:/haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('D:/lena.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,170,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,100),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It currently works great. I now want to add an if-else statement to take a costume action if a face is detected or not. Where would I place that statement, and what parameter would I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"faces" is your list of found faces.  You're already looping through it in the "for (x,y,w,h) in faces:" line.  If there are no faces found, then this will be an empty list.

In Python, a conditional test on an empty list = False, and True if the list isn't empty.  So, if you want to do something if a face is detected, then try:

```
    if faces:
        do-something
```

Similarly for all the other detected objects such as eyes.

Comment: Your welcome.  Please upvote and check off this as the answer if it was useful to you.